# Can the corner frequency of thermal noise change with change in source impedance?

Tags: operational-amplifier

In EMG there is a certain level of thermal noise created at the electrode-gel-skin interface which depends on the skin-electrode impedance (also known as source impedance).

I have been able get the thermal noise data for only dry electrodes of different materials. Dry electrodes are the same electrodes in this case but placed without any Gel. At 100kOhms impedance the white noise is the same as any 100KOhms resistor but the different electrodes have different corner frequency and the exact curve of the 1/f noise on the graph is different as well. (Noise density per square root Hz on the y-axis and frequency on the x-axis, like in op-amps data sheets)

Will/can the corner frequency change if the source impedance is reduced to <5kOhms using a gel or  the corner frequency and curve will be the same as 100kOhms data except that the noise density for white and pink noise will be reduced to a <5kOhms resistor level?

Comment: Show your schematic, can you provide an equivalent input network? What you're suggesting is possible

Comment: @ErnestoG Thanks. I have not drawn a schematic. But does this image help? https://pubs.acs.org/cms/10.1021/acsomega.2c00282/asset/images/medium/ao2c00282_0008.gif  The electrode-skin interface forms a galvanic half-cell (Geddes, 1972)

Answer (score 1):

Depends on how you model the thermal noise and what the source is for the thermal noise. Noise from resistors is white or Johnson noise. The rms power of the noise is based off of the noise height (which is the same for all frequencies) and how much of those frequencies you are allowing in your analog system (bandwidth). The height of the noise is dependent on the temperature and the resistance.

If the desire is to lower the noise content (rms noise) then there lower either the temperature (which is probably not possible), the resistance, or the bandwidth of the analog system.

1/f or flicker noise comes from transistors and other silicon devices (not resistors, if you want to lower this noise this will be dependent on the opamp or transistor that is used to amplifiy the signal (the actual noise is dependent on the construction of the device). Other devices are avalible such as chopper operational amplifiers that can eliminate 1/f noise by chopping DC and rectifying and reconstructing the DC signal which also modulates the 1/f noise to a higher frequency where it can be filtered out.

It is likely that all of the 1/f noise is coming from the electronics (especially if the electrode-gel-skin interface is modled as a resistor which would be white noise). However there also could be some ion exchange happening at the electrode which could be generating noise. So it really depends on if you can use a completely white noise resistor to modle the human skin interface or if there are more processes going on that contribute to noise.

> Will/can the corner frequency change if the source impedance is
> reduced to <5kOhms using a gel or the corner frequency and curve will
> be the same as 100kOhms data except that the noise density for white
> and pink noise will be reduced to a <5kOhms resistor level?

If the electrode-gel-skin interface can be modled as a resistor then lowering the impedance will lower the noise. Another thing that can be done is to cut the bandwidth as much as you can. Use electronics that have little or no 1/f noise, usually the 0 to 10Hz 1/f noise number is specified in datasheets of opamps and instrumentation amplifiers, select one with a low number.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Chopper op-amp does not remove the 1/f noise of the sensors or sources other than the op-amps. https://www.analog.com/en/analog-dialogue/articles/understanding-and-eliminating-1-f-noise.html

Comment: By "lowering the impedance will lower the noise", are you referring to corner frequency or just the overall reduction in noise level?

Comment: No the resistance, if there is some way to change the sensor to lower resistance then you get less noise, if you design low nose amplifiers the resistance of resistors needs to be lowered. Same guess for sensors

Comment: There is no way to remove 1/f noise from sensors if the bandwidth includes DC, what I'm saying is you need to eliminate it from the analog signal chain. Temperature controlling electronics also helps

Comment: Say the corner freq. is 70 Hz and EMG Bandpass filter is from 35-200Hz. If I am understanding it correctly, by having a high pass analog filter say at 0.05 Hz there will be a reduction or elimination of 1/f noise. Could you share any example so I can understand how much of a reduction to expect in the noise density?

Comment: I'd need a circuit to do that, you have to do a noise analysis

Comment: @tilly, The chopper technique and its equivalents reduce or cancel the 1/f noise present in the components and not in the source. As you can see, if the application allows it (if you don't need the frequencies found in 1/f noise), you'll generally need a high-pass filter to attenuate 1/f noise, a low-pass filter to attenuate broadband thermal noise and perhaps a notch filter for 50/60Hz.